# Provide role for user in Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, role-manager

I am new to Azure integration with web app. Can I know is there any tutorial available to assign role to user that login with Azure AD? Such as `UserManager.AddToRole(userId, "Admin")` for a standard login. I need a full guide on how to assign role to user that login with Azure AD. Thanks!

PS: Im using ASP.NET with WebForm, not MVC.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to figure out how you implement authorization in your application. Azure AD has 3 primary mechanisms. From: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-multitenant-identity-app-roles/

> **Roles using Azure AD App Roles:**  The SaaS provider defines the application roles by adding them to the application manifest. After a customer signs up, an admin for the customer's AD directory assigns users to the roles. When a user signs in, the user's assigned roles are sent as claims.

If you pick this approach, you can POST to the Azure AD Graph's /appRoleAssignments to assign a group or user to an application role like so:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals/{service_principal_object_id}/appRoleAssignedTo
Body
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id":"{role_object_id}",
  "principalId":"{user/group_object_id}",
  "resourceId":"{service_principal_object_id}"
}
```

See this link for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#AppRoleAssignmentEntity

> **Roles using Azure AD security groups:**  In this approach, roles are represented as AD security groups. The application assigns permissions to users based on their security group memberships.

If you pick this approach, you can POST to the Azure AD Graph's /groups to assign a user to a group like so:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{group_object_id}/$links/members?api-version
Body
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/{user_object_id}"
}
```

See this link for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers

> **Roles using an application role manager:**  With this approach, application roles are not stored in Azure AD at all. Instead, the application stores the role assignments for each user in its own DB — for example, using the RoleManager class in ASP.NET Identity.

If you pick this approach, then you'd basically continue to use AddToRole.

Be sure to check out the first link I referenced for details on how to implement the first two approaches.